# write Fast kinect data on Hard Disk

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++

I want to build a face dataset. So I write a grabber program with (Visual c ++) that grabs color/depth/infrared and some other data from kinect for windows  with 60 fps and  then save them on hard disk . it take a lot of time so i can not save more than 10 frames in a second and lots of frames are dropped. I try using fileStorage(opencv) to save data a yaml but it's slow too. I'm thinking about using two threads , one for grabbing data and another for saving . but data communication between two independent threads are the main issue.
What is the best solution to save data without loosing frames?

Comment: compute the needed bandwith (60fps*sizeOfAFrame) and compare it to your hardware writing bandwith. If you theoretically CAN write all the frames you can optimize it by caching and then writing from a different thread. I've seen file systems where some delay occured after some seconds, which was fixed by multi-threading. Writing with fileStorage is probably much slower than writing raw data, because data size probably drastically increases and you need additional time for formatting/conversion.

Comment: OP: Are you certain about the 60 FPS? From what I can find it's 30. Still, RGB image at 1920x1080 is 6075 KiB, 16bit depth and IR at 512x424 is 424 KiB each --> 6923 KiB per frame at 30 Hz gives ~ 203 MiB/s. As Micka says, depends on your hardware. You should definitely write raw data, you're unlikely to be able to compress this anywhere close to real time (at least not with CPU only). Show some code, and provide some more details about HW and how much you actually want to save (time wise - length of one continous sequence of frames).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for all your help.
I solve the problem with defining two threads, a shared memory (queue) and a mutex.

```
//I have a passenger class that store all data including images in it
#include "passenger.h"
//I define a queue from passenger class
queue<passenger> passengerQueue;
//and a mutex 
std::mutex myMutex;
void GrabberThreadFunc()
{
     //get the data and store it in a passenger object
     if (nearPassenger.valid)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(myMutex);
        passengerQueue.push(nearPassenger);
     }
}
void SavetThreadFunc()
{
     if (!passengerQueue.empty())
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(myMutex);
        passengerQueue.front().SaveData();
        passengerQueue.pop();
   }
}
```

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

```
thread GrabberThread(GrabberThreadFunc);
thread SaverThread(SaverThreadFunc);

if (GrabberThread.joinable())
    GrabberThread.join();

if (SaverThread.joinable())
    SaverThread.join();

return 0;
```

}

Comment: R.y.z, could you share your solution?

Answer (score -1):

Caching the 60 or more frames in memory via `mmap()` and using `sendfile` for saving the files. Ofcourse some synchronization is required between caching and saving.

Suppose you employ a `vector<JOB>` having predefined number of elements say 600 (60*number_of_sec_which_are_cached).

```
struct JOB 
{
    int second_number; //second related to time 
    int frame_number; //frame number in second specified by "JOB::second_number"
    unsigned char *buf; //frame buffer
    unsigned int buf_length; //number of bytes in frame which would be a fixed number.
    int valid; 
};
```

Grabber will make `JOB::valid = 1` on fetching the frame.

FileSavingThread will use `JOB::valid` to identify whether the frame is ready to save if `JOB::valid==1` and after saving will make `JOB::valid=0`.

Now if [Atomic operations library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic) is used for `JOB::valid` then you can easily avoid mutex for synchronization.

Then, Grabber has to just find a element in vector (by going through all the elements) which has `JOB::valid==0` and store the frame in that particular element.

Similary, FileSavingThread has to find a element in vector which has `JOB::valid==1` and store the frame specified in that element to file.

Depending upon the performance, you can then try increasing the number of elements in vector or increase the number of FileSavingThread or both.

`//-------------------------------------------------------------------------`

- New Method 2: **Using an existing file which is Memory Mapped.**
- Reference: [Memory Mapped File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx)

Here, if we know how many frames or how much data corresponding to number of time seconds are to be saved then we can create a file of that much size before hand and memory map that file. Then, saving the frames would be as simple as writing to memory in contiguous manner. Caching and I/O will be automatically managed by OS in optimal way.

This is possible because all the parameters w.r.t frames involved in calculation are fixed.

Reading of frames can also be done by Memory Mapping the saved file. If a single frame is required then again, the calculation of offset from start of saved file is easy to calculate as all the parameters required to calculate the offset of a particular frame are fixed.

Now what benefits are there in reading/writing in such manner can be read here [What Do Memory-Mapped Files Have to Offer?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately you need a mutex on the `std::vector`, using the atomic library on a member of the vector doesn't help. When the Grabber adds a job to the vector, it might reallocate which would **move** all existing jobs and their atomic variables. The FileSavingThread therefore needs to lock the vector while reading it.

Comment: Visual Studio implies Windows -- there's no `senfile()` on Windows. Memory mapping uses a different API as well, not `mmap()`. You should explain the use mmap in more detail (It seems you mean to use anonymous shared memory, but it's not obvious). Synchronization is not a trivial issue, concrete example with at least some pseudocode or references to related answers would be useful. The general idea is not bad, but the answer could be a lot more detailed.

Comment: @MSalters: If you had read the answer carefully then you will find a line "a vector<JOB> having predefined number of elements". So there is no chance of reallocation or even adding a new element to vector which will require locking. I already gave a though on the issue you mentioned. Also, the Grabber will make `JOB:valid=1` after filling data in `JOB::buf`, till then FileSavingThread will find `JOB:valid==0`. And since atomic operation (TestAndSet()) is used to set `JOB:valid` therefore there is actually be no need of locking for synchronization.

Comment: @DanMašek: Yes, you are correct. I did not notice that it is related to "Windows". But then again, APIs similar to `sendfile()` and `memory-mapping` are available in WIndows as well. I just wanted to present an idea to encounter the problem.

Comment: @sameerkn: If you have a predefiend number, why aren't you using a `std::array<JOB, 600>` ?

Comment: @MSalters: Am not completely into new versions of C++. :) Thanks for the tip.